# Speed up Image Feature Extraction

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop

It's the program of import multiple images and extract feature.
The problem is that it's too slow
I think it's because there's so many for loop.

For example

```
for q in range(0, height-32 , 32):  
  for w in range(0 , width-32 ,32):
   for j in range(0,64,8):
       for n in range(0,64,8):
```

How can I change my code to speed up?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import dct
from PIL import Image
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def image_open(path):
    image_list = []
    #for filename in glob.glob('path/*.jpg'): 
    for filename in glob.glob(path+'/*.jpg'):  
     im=Image.open(filename)
     image_list.append(im)

    return image_list

path = 'C:\\Users\\LG\\PycharmProjects\\photo'   

images = image_open(path)


for i in range(0, len(images)):     
 box3 = (0,0,256,256)
 a = images[i].crop(box3)

 (y,cb,cr) = a.split()       
 width , height = y.size  
 y.show()

 for q in range(0, height-32 , 32):  
  for w in range(0 , width-32 ,32):



     for j in range(0,64,8):
       for n in range(0,64,8):

     print(w/32)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with all these loops? If we don't know why you are looping so many times then we can't help improve your algorithm.

Comment: question title is really a big topic :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using so many loops so I’d suggest you try to improve that as best as you can first.

After that, look into threads. [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

If the number of images being consumed is low, you could run the operation on each image on a separate thread.